# recv() in C socket returns 0 for some requests

Tags: c, sockets

I have an issue with recv() and read() methods as well, both return 0 byte for some of my requests. On the other hand, I made a java application to do the same, and it always get me the response from the server, I mean the issue only happens with my C application, but not happen on Java. So please revise my below main method for that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <limits.h>
#define PORT 7142 


typedef unsigned char BYTE;

//function to convert string to byte array
void string2ByteArray(char* input, BYTE* output)
{

    int loop;
    int i;

    loop = 0;
    i = 0;

    while (input[loop] != '\0')
    {
        output[i++] = (unsigned char)input[loop++];

    }
}


int toDigit(char ch, int index) {
    int digit;
    if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
        digit = ch - '0';
    if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'F')
        digit = ch - 'A' + 10;
    if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'f')
        digit = ch - 'a' + 10;

    if (digit == -1) {
        // throw new Exception("Illegal hexadecimal character " + ch + " at index " + index);
        return -1;
    }
    return digit;
}


void ToHex(BYTE data[], BYTE out[])
{
    int len = strlen(data);
    int i, j, f;
    if ((len & 0x01) != 0) {
        //throw new Exception("Odd number of characters.");
    }

    // two characters form the hex value.
    for (i = 0, j = 0; j < len; i++) {
        f = toDigit(data[j], j) << 4;
        j++;
        f = f | toDigit(data[j], j);
        j++;

        out[i] = (f & 0xFF);


    }

}


void encodeHex(int data[], char output[1024], int len) {
    int l = len, i = 0, j = 0;
    char out[l << 1];
    char DIGITS_LOWER[16] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };
    // two characters form the hex value.

    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < l; i++) {
        out[j++] =  DIGITS_LOWER[(unsigned int)((0xF0 & data[i]) >> 4)];
        out[j++] =  DIGITS_LOWER[(unsigned int)(0x0F & data[i])];

    }

    out[j] = '\0';
    strcpy(output, out);
}

int main(){
    char ascii_str[] = "Hello world!";
    int i;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int sock = 0, sRet, rdret = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    char sbuffer[] = "005a600003000001006038048020C090001663917561001880293100001701091820291201002100346391756100188029D2301521107398300f32323230303737373232323030303037202020202020203933385a4f1aceb81b09d7";
    int len = strlen(sbuffer);
    BYTE arr[len], arr1[len], bufferbyte[1024];
    char buffer[1024] ="";
    int tempBuffer[1024] = { 0 };
    char Recv[1024] = "";
    int* ptr;

    string2ByteArray(sbuffer, arr);

    ToHex(arr, arr1);

    if ((sock =  socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        printf("\n Socket creation error \n");
        return -1;
    }

    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, "10.16.4.212", &serv_addr.sin_addr) <= 0)  
    {
        printf("\nInvalid address/ Address not supported \n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        printf("\nConnection Failed \n");
        return -1;
    }

    sRet = send(sock, arr1, strlen(sbuffer), 0);
    printf("Hello message sent %d\n", sRet);

    rdret = recv(sock, buffer, 100,0);

    printf("Recieved Size1: %d\n", rdret);

    {

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        for (i = 0; i <= rdret; i++)
        {
            if (buffer[i] == 0)
            {
                buffer[i] = buffer[i] + 256;

            }
            tempBuffer[j] = buffer[i];

            ++j;

        }
                encodeHex(tempBuffer, Recv, j - 1);

        printf("\nRecieved Data: %s\n", Recv);


    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you may be overflowing some of your arrays, for example, `string2ByteArray()` does not NUL terminate its output, but `ToHex()` does expect a NUL terminated input.

Comment: There's lot of questionable code in your program. For example `string2ByteArray` isn't really any different from `memcpy`, and isn't really needed (all you need to do to "convert" a `char` string to an `unsigned char` string is a cast, as in `(BYTE *) sbuffer`). Not to mention your mix of null-terminated strings and non-terminated strings. Or lack of bounds checking in general. Plenty of possible undefined behaviors around, all which could lead to any kind of problems (like sending invalid data to the peer so it closes the connection).

Comment: @rodrigo my issue happens after I send My Message it's been delivered to server side, and even server send me a response, but I cannot receive it on recv() method

Comment: You didn't give us any hint about the other part of the communication...Neither the Java code...

Comment: `memset` call is wrong, second parameter should certainly be 0 (value 0) and not `'0'` (not ASCII value of char 0).

Answer (score 4):

When `recv` or `read` returns `0` it means that the other end have nicely closed its connection, and you should do the same.

This is well-documented behavior and any socket book or tutorial should have mentioned it.

Comment: „Nicely”, that was Good :).

Comment: well, that's so true, but I couldn't understand why I cannot receive my data on receiving buffer, while I can do with other requests. also I can receive data on C++, or java, for the same server connection.